# Subnets sets by a wifi and wire router

Tags: networking, router, subnet

Is it generally possible to have wifi & wired clients of a router on the same subnet so that they see each other on the same LAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most consumer grade routers are set up to give out IPs on the same subnet by default.  It might make sense from a security standpoint to separate wireless and wired clients, but in a standard home situation, there is really no need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no reason that they need to be separated unless you have QoS rules or some other special need for it.